# Trouble installing gawk

Tags: macos, installation, unix

I'm trying to install aqua nmr and it requires gawk. I follow the directions in the install and in the make install step I get:

```
sh-3.2# make install
cd doc && make info
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `info'.
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin /usr/local/share/awk \
                /usr/local/lib /usr/local/info /usr/local/man/man1 /usr/loca/libexec/awk
/opt/molmol-2k2-universal/install -c gawk /usr/local/bin && chmod 755 /usr/loca/bin/gawk
chmod: /usr/local/bin/gawk: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

One thing that catches my eye is the `/opt/molmol-2k2-universal/install`...

I have no idea why it would be doing anything will molmol to install gawk. (MolMol is a molecular graphics program)

Comment: Check your path. It looks like it wants to run `install`, and the molmol one is on there. Also, did you copy/paste the message? There are several `loca` instead of `local`.

Comment: Whats the best way of figuring out how to force it to use the system install instead of the molmol one?

Comment: Did you check your path to make sure I'm right about this? And if so, you tried setting your path to a list of directories that don't include `/opt/molmol-2k2-universal`?

Comment: Also, on OS X, it's easiest to install unix tools using one of the package managers Fink, Macports and Homebrew.

Comment: @Nate In that case, please accept my answer below to mark your question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

Clean up your path, so that it doesn't use this `install`

Or install it using Homebrew, Macports, or Fink instead.

```
brew install gawk
```